# Rxjs - Merging an async response with a sync response

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I started doing functional chains using RxJs 5 and really enjoying it. I noticed a pattern that I encounter often, but couldn't find a way to solve it using RxJs's methods.

I get **some async data** using a `value` and **merge them** with value itself.

Let me show you in code:

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(somePromise) // doesn't really matter
  .flatMap(value => {  // this is the original value I have
    const promise = aFunctionThatReturnsPromise(value);
    return Promise.all([promise, value])); // I created a promise using this value, but I still want to keep value as well
  })
  .map(([promiseValue, originalValue]) => ({ // I merge new produced values with the value itself and get rid of array.
    value1: promiseValue.value1,
    value2: promiseValue.value2
    originalValue: originalValue
  }))
  // ...rest of the chain...
```

As it can be seen, this means to create a combined promise with `Promise.all` just to keep `value` and a cleanup phase with `map` to make things nicer for following parts of the chain.

Is there a **built-in** RxJs construct for this kinds of pattern? Or is there another approach that yields to cleaner more understandable solution?

Comment: Why the observable here? Why don't you just use promises?

Comment: @TamasHegedus in the sample code, I don't really need observable. But that is pretty simplified for demonstration, and the real code I have, I do need observables. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to do something with the input value combined with the output value people tend to write:

```
Rx.Observable.of('foo')
  .mergeMap(i => aFunctionThatReturnsPromise(i)
    .map(asyncResult => ({ foo: i, result: asyncResult})
  )
```

This pattern can be simplified using the [`mergeMap` `resultSelector`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) (`flatMap` if rxjs4) into the following:

```
Rx.Observable.of('foo')
  .mergeMap(
    i => aFunctionThatReturnsPromise(i),
    (i, asyncResult) => ({ syncValue: i, asyncResult })
  )
// ... rest of the chain
```

This gives you acces to your original input value and every output value received. Additional bonus is that `mergeMap` will wrap your promise into an observable without using `Rx.Observable.fromPromise()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure RxJS, it's common to nest observable chains to keep previous values in context:

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(somePromise)
  .flatMap(value =>
    Rx.Observable.fromPromise(aFunctionThatReturnsPromise(value))
      .map((promiseValue) => ({
        value1: promiseValue.value1,
        value2: promiseValue.value2,
        originalValue: value
      }))
  )
// ...rest of the chain...
```

Can get out of hands quickly if used too much, so you usually try to *reduce* the data (and get back to the outer stream) as soon as you can.